# How to listen to audio output by application

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, sampling

## Background

I'm working on a music player, and want any sort of audio visualizer to be part of it. I've already made a previous post specifically targeting python-vlc, but I guess not too many people know about it. Here is the post in question: [How to get audio samples from python-VLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049965/how-to-get-audio-samples-from-python-vlc)

## What I need

I need a way to listen to audio output, preferably by application although it is not completely necessary. It must be a python module.

## What I found

- A bunch of tutorials regarding audio input from the microphone, which is NOT what I need
- Two `swhardware.com` tutorials with audio visualizers

  - https://swharden.com/blog/2016-07-19-realtime-audio-visualization-in-python/
  - Another one from 2013 but I can't find the link
- PyAudio tutorials also using the microphone
- [Listening audio output with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723276/listening-audio-output-with-python)
- terminatorX on Linux; it uses the microphone
- squishyball on Linux; it doesn't support all audio files
- livefft; uses pyqt***4*** so I couldn't even test it

## Alternatives

Any python module or linux terminal that can provide a list of audio samples from any audio file. Similar to `pydub.AudioSegement.get_array_of_samples()`

## What I don't need

- More suggestions to use pydub's `get_array_of_samples()`

  - Pydub doesn't read the audio file correctly and quickly gets out of sync from already playing audio
- More tutorials of how to get audio from the microphone
- Answers on how to strip audio from a video file with ffmpeg

Comment: What platform?  It's a bit different on every OS.

Comment: I use Linux, but I'm sure I can find a way to make it work on Windows or macOS.